# Accessibilty : jaws18 - every letter entered in the username input field is read twice in chrome

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, section508

Every letter entered in the username textbox is read twice by JAWS.
JAWS version - 18
Browser - Chrome

Code:

```
<!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="smalltext" for="email">{{ 'sign.email' | translate }}</label>  
      <input id="email" name="emailaddress" ng-model="login.user.username" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-md smalltext" required autocomplete="new-username">
       <!-- ff solution not to remeber credentials -->
      <input type="text" class="hidden">
      <p class="danger" ng-show="(loginform.$submitted) && loginform.emailaddress.$error.required" class="help-block" aria-live="polite">{{ 'el_txt_validateUsername' | translate }}.</p>
      <p class="danger" ng-show="(loginform.$submitted) && loginform.emailaddress.$error.email" class="help-block" aria-live="polite">Please enter the email address in a valid format.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: There isn't a question here.

Comment: Do you have any `aria-live` regions (including the alert or status role) as an ancestor to this text box? Also, which version of Chrome?

Comment: @andrewmacpherson i have edited the code in the question...and the version of chrome is 70.0.3538.110